# Using GAE users service - can't get "sign-in as a different user"

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, cookies, openid

I'm using the GAE users service for login/logout mechanism, with create_login_url, etc, and it all works fine. BTW, I use the federated OpenID option.

But I have one problem - since the users service checks with user=users.get_current_user() then if a user is logged in to his gmail, it automatically logs him into my service. This is OK, but what if a different user wants to login? 
how can I redirect the user to a page such as the "sign in as a different user"?

I tried to remove the cookie I'm creating, and it gets removed:

> ```
>   if not (self.request.cookies.has_key('ACSID')):
>         logging.debug('no cookies')
>         self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
>         return
> ```

then I see the log for "no cookies", but the next thing happens is that it logs the user in, without putting him on the "google accounts" login page... So the user never have the opportunity to login as a different user.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't know that in principle there's a good way for an OpenID relying party to cause a user to be logged out of the providing service; using Google logins does this and it's very annoying to be logged out of Gmail by logging out of a random appengine site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can think of is; you could try showing a link to `/_ah/login_required` which will trigger the OpenID signin page and (hopefully) also contain a "sign in as someone else" button.

This doesn't fully solve the issue, as the problem is complicated by multiple openid providers.

It's not possible to force someone to sign out of their provider's site AFAIK.

Full example of creating the login/this-is-not-me page:

### Add a login path to your `app.yaml`

```
- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: app.py
```

### Create an OpenID login handler to create a relevent login url

```
class OpenIDHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        """Begins the OpenID flow/Google Apps discovery"""
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(
            dest_url='http://yourappid.appspot.com',
            _auth_domain=None,
            federated_identity=self.request.get('domain')))
```

### Add an OpenID handler to your wgsi app (probably `main.py`):

```
def main():
    ROUTES = [
        ('/_ah/login_required',      handlers.OpenIDHandler),
    ]
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(ROUTES, debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Now you can visit `/_ah/login_required` whenever you want someone to be prompted with the login (or 'this is not me' page)

Comment: Thanks Chris. What do you mean by "showing a link to /ah/login_required"?

Comment: as in `<a href="http://yourapp.appspot.com/_ah/login_required">sign in as someone else</a>`

Comment: but it doesn't work... for a weird reason /_ah/login_required gets me to a non-page... ("Oops! This link appears to be broken.")

Comment: Sorry I was assuming you were already using a login url of that form, extended the answer with full details of setting up a login url

Comment: ok... so most of the text you've put I already had :) the change I did was instead of using self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)), I now use   self.redirect(users.create_login_url(dest_url=self.request.uri, _auth_domain=None, federated_identity=self.request.get('www.google.com')))
but the same happens... it logs me in. I will try to update my question even more, so it will be more clear what I do.